# Or/And Filter in HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I am new to `HtmlAgilityPack` before and for a long time i have been using `WinistaHtmlParser`. But switching to `HtmlAgilityPack` i see what i had been missing.

In Winista if i wanted to take data from multiple Elements (Div,span,table) i used and/or filer.

I am not sure how to apply and/or filter in `HtmlAgilityPack` .

Example:

```
<div id ="jobListing">
 <div class="evenRow">job1</div>
 <div class="oddRow">job2</div>
 <div class="evenRow">job3</div>
 <div class="oddRow">job4</div>
</div>
```

I know i can get the Div like ,

```
HtmlNodeCollection allJobs = path.SelectNodes("//div[@class='evenRow']");
```

But i want to get divs with both classes , i dont want to just get by div .So how to apply a or filter here?

something like:

```
HtmlNodeCollection allJobs = path.SelectNodes("//div[@class='evenRow'] + //div[@class='oddRow'] ");
```

And also how to apply and filter like if i want to get the div below on both class and id:.

```
<div id="abc" class="123"> text </div>
```

Any help appreciated  i always wanted to learn these filter on HtmlAgilityPack but never got time, but today i have to use this :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `OR` together attribute filters like so:

```
HtmlNodeCollection allJobs = 
     path.SelectNodes("//div[@class='evenRow' or @class='oddRow']");
```

Ref.: [XPath Examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086.aspx)

Comment: waiting for the timeout will accept your answer after 5 mins.